# The algorithm receives a natural number N > 1 as input and builds a new number R from it as follows:

Tags: python-3.x

Python.

It's a problem:
The algorithm receives a natural number N > 1 as input and builds a new number R from it as follows:

1. We translate the number N into binary notation.
2. Invert all bits of the number except the first one.
3. Convert to decimal notation.
4. Add the result with the original number N.

The resulting number is the desired number R. Indicate the smallest odd number N for which the result of this algorithm is greater than 310. In your answer, write this number in decimal notation.

This is my solution:

```
for n in range(2, 10000):
    s = bin(n)[2:]
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i+1] == 0:
            s[i] = '1'
        else:
            s[i] = 'k'
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == 'k':
            s[i] = '0'
    h = int(s, 2)
    r = h + n
    if n % 2 == 1 and r > 310:
        print(n)
        break
```

So it doesn't work and i dont know why. I am now preparing for the exam, so I would be grateful if you could explain the reason to me

the bin function returns a string and my idea is to go through the binary elements of this string, starting from the second element, to replace 0 with 1, and 1 with k. Then iterate over the elements of a new line again and replace k with 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me longer than I expected but feels good.
Comments might make it look chaotic but will make it easily understandable.

```
#since N is supposed to be odd and >1 the loop is being run from 3
for N in range(3, 10000,2):
#appending binary numbers to the list bin_li
    bin_li=[]
    bin_li.append((bin(N)[2:])) 
    for i in bin_li:
        #print("bin_li item :",i)
        #storing 1st digit to be escaped in j
        j=i[:1]
        #reversing the digits
        for k in i[1:]:
            if k=='0':
                #putting together the digits after reversing
                j=j+'1'
            else:
                j=j+'0'
        #print("reversed item :",j) #note first digit is escaped       
                #converting back to decimal
        dec=int(j,2)
    
        R=dec+N
        #print("current sum:---------" ,R)
        if R > 310:
            print("The number N :",N)
            print("The reversed binary number:",dec)
            print("Sum :",R)
            break
    #break will only break the inner loop
    # for reference https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python/
    else:
        continue
    break
```